# How to Save PyCharm Embedded Terminal Tabs?

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, pycharm, tabs

Is there a way to save the Embedded Tabs so each time you open PyCharm you don't have to reconfigure the tab names? It seems like such a simple issue to have but I am unable to find any information on it. This is the documentation on JetBrains Site for [Embedded Tabs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html) but it mentions nothing about saving them to the default layout. Each time you open the IDE you are required to click the plus sign and rename the tab.

I have tried exporting settings and re-importing them with no luck at all. It has nothing to do with them theme from what I can tell.

[image: PyCharm Embedded Tabs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117946) about saving terminal tabs between sessions, please vote :)

Comment: Looks like it has been implemented since a while (it recently got fixed after a regression).